# Azure devops failing to download private npm packages

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps for my node application, but I have private npm packages that fail with a 401 whenever DevOps runs the `npm install` during the pipeline. I have run the additional npm task runner for authenticating where the Registry URL is set to https://npm.pkg.github.com/ along with the Username and Password for the npm account. Finally, I have created a .npmrc file locally within the project that contains `@[organisation_name_here]:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/`. However, when I still run the pipeline I still receive the following error:

`npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized: @***/schemas@^1.0.8`

I have seen and read about the ability to use Azure Artifacts, however, I would prefer not to avoid using them as I am slowly migrating over to AWS. If Azure Artifacts is the only way, then please help! I'm slowly going insane XD lol

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If your `.npmrc` contains Azure Artifacts registries from a different organization or use a third-party authenticated package repository, you'll need to set up [npm service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-npm) and specify them in the `customEndpoint` input.

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_packaging/{feed}/npm/registry/
@{scope}:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{otherorganization}/_packaging/{feed}/npm/registry/
@{otherscope}:registry=https://{thirdPartyRepository}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
```

Check more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm-authenticate?view=azure-devops